# Download file from SQL Server to store in application folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I've been tasked to transfer files from SQL to a ashx handler in another application which we don't manage. It looks like the ashx handler needs the file location to come from a directory. So my assumption is to first download the file to a local folder in my app. So I've created a "Files" directory in my application App_Data directory "App_Data/Files/".

So my approach would be to download the file to this folder then transfer it via the ashx handler. **However, I cannot find an example of how to download a file stored in SQL Server to a local directory in an application**. Does anyone know how to do this or have an example of downloading a file stored in SQL Server to a specific folder within the app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195292/download-file-from-sql-server-using-c-sharp

Comment: Are your files being stored in SQL using Filestream, or BLOB/varbinary?

Comment: The file content is stored as an "image" data type.

Answer (score -1):

After some trial and error, this seems to be working for me. the byte array is the data stored in the database. So from the byte array we can create the file and post it to a folder in the app.

```
byte[] fileContent = fap.FileContent;
string fileName = "fileName.pdf";
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files/");
string pathAndFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName);
File.WriteAllBytes(pathAndFile, fileContent);
```